# Is there a way to specify an NUnit test as "extra credit"?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I have a few tests for an API, and I would like to be able to express certain tests that reflect "aspirational" or "extra credit" requirements - in other words, it's great if they pass, but fine if they don't. For instance:

```
[Test]
public void RequiredTest()
{
    // our client is using positive numbers in DoThing();
    int result = DoThing(1);
    Assert.That( /* result is correct */ );
}

[Test]
public void OptionalTest()
{
    // we do want to handle negative numbers, but our client is not yet using them
    int result = DoThing(-1);
    Assert.That( /* result is correct */ );
}
```

I know about the `Ignore` attribute, but I would like to be able to mark `OptionalTest` in such a way that it still runs on the CI server, but is fine if it does not pass - as soon as it does, I would like to take notice and perhaps make it a requirement. Is there any major unit test framework that supports this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any NUnit attribute that would provide the behavior you describe. The complete list of supported attributes is here:

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Warnings to achieve this. That way - your test will print a 'warning' output, but not be a failure, and not fail your CI build.

See: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Warnings

> as soon as it does, I would like to take notice and perhaps make it a requirement.

This part's a slightly separate requirement! Depends a lot on how you want to 'take notice'! Consider looking at Custom Attributes - it may be possible to write an `IWrapSetUpTearDown` attribute, which sends an email when the relevant test passes. See the docs, here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/ICommandWrapper-Interface

The latter is a more unusual requirement - I would expect to have to do something custom to fit your needs there!

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean that I wanted to be told programmatically the moment it passed. I just meant that I wanted to have the test still running on CI so that I can still inspect whether it passes or fails in the logs.

Comment: Sounds like warnings are what you need then. =)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the closest one. It does seem a little too strong for my needs so far (I would prefer not to be notified in logs unless the test passes), but it does work here, and probably would be the best situation if we strongly believe that a client will make it a requirement.

Comment: In that case, you may also want to look at `Assert.Inconclusive()`. Although, I think a warning better meets your needs semantically. :-)